# Chromium-OS Freescale i.MX6 Dual Cortex-A9

Tags: arm, chromium, chromium-os

i'm looking for help to compile and run Chromium-os on a freescale i.mx6 dual core.
any one know how to do this?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the yocto project you may try using this layer:

https://github.com/OSSystems/meta-browser

Regards